# Code uploaded to flash memory

Tags: embedded

My question is when I include any library in the "main.c" file and use just one function or two from it, what is actually uploaded to the flash memory? All of the library or just the functions I used?

Comment: Usually you can instruct your compiler to perform dead code elimination. Most will do it automatically. You will probably get more specific response if you provide more information about which compiler and what version you are using.

Comment: You don't include libraries in the source code! And C headers don't contain definitions (except for `inline` functions), but only declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library is composed of multiple compiled object code files; the linker will extract and link only those object files necessary to fully resolve all references in your code.  If an object file contains multiple functions some of which are unused, you may end up with redundant code, but a well designed library will deliberately have one public function per object file to avoid this.

Your linker will have the ability to output a map file that will tell you *exactly* what is included in your final image and where it is located.  There will often be a great deal of code you have not called directly but which is called either by functions you *have* linked or by compiler generated code such as software floating-point support for example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by library and how you wrote those functions.  It should be trivial to use objdump or maybe readelf to dump the binary and see what is actually in there.  If for example you are talking about global functions in main.c (ones without static in front of them) that you didnt use anywhere, those end up in your flash/binary.  Likewise if you have another file x.c that you make an object from and it has global functions you didnt use but you linked x.o into your binary then all of those functions will be there (talking about gnu tools btw, others may try harder).  If you create a library x.a then it ideally picks and chooses only what you needed.

If you are using clang/llvm then you can choose to optimize at the project level instead of just at the source file level as with gcc.  So not only is it possible to optimize out dead code not used from any individual file, but even library functions if the optimizer determines those are better served inlined it can optimize those out too.

it depends heavily on the tools you are using and how you are using, as asked it is way too broad.